# Why does loading LDV in this sequence reduce computation?

Tags: largedatavolumes

I'm reading the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_best_practices_api_loading_data.htm) on loading LDV and to reduce computation the docs recommend this sequence of tasks below. I don't understand why #3 is called out and why it should be done after step 2.

1. If possible for initial loads, populate roles before populating
   sharing rules.
2. Load users into roles. Load record data with owners, triggering calculations in the role hierarchy.
3. Configure public groups and queues, and let those computations propagate.
4. Add sharing rules one at a time, letting computations for each rule finish before adding the next one

Comment: The ultimate goal of the Platform is to calculate access control tuples (user, resource, grant/deny).  Groups and queues break down into users, thus Platform needs this knowledge to arrive at a tuple. Whether #3 needs to be after #2 or #2 and #3 can be done in parallel is another question.